# Applying @app_commands.checks.cooldowns to an entire slash command group in a different file

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to have a slash command group that can rename a text channel by adding an emoji in front (or removing that emoji entirely). However Discord's rate limit for changing text channel names is 2 every 600 seconds. I understand how to apply a cooldown to a singular slash command. However when a whole group has this limitation together, applying a cooldown check is not working.

**Here's my main file with an error handler for cooldowns:**

```py
### a ton of imports above this line as well as pulling in my token variables.

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+" | aio is now running!")
    print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+" | Username: ", bot.user.name)
    print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+" | User ID: ", bot.user.id)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="AI Drake"))
    try:
        await bot.load_extension("slashcommands.move")
        await bot.load_extension("slashcommands.colors")
        await bot.load_extension("slashcommands.test")
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+f" | Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print(str(datetime.datetime.now())+" | Ready!")

@bot.tree.error
async def on_app_command_error(
    interaction: discord.Interaction, error: app_commands.AppCommandError
):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await interaction.response.send_message(str(error))

bot.run(bot_token)
```

**In a separate file called colors.py which I use load_extension to add it to the tree:**

```py
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(2,600.0,key=lambda i:(i.channel.id))
class ColorGroup(app_commands.Group):
    @app_commands.command(name="green", description="Mark this channel with a green emoji: ")
    async def green(self,interaction:discord.Interaction):

        if interaction.channel.name.startswith(""):
            await interaction.response.send_message("> **This channel is already marked green.**", ephemeral=True)
        elif interaction.channel.name.startswith("") or interaction.channel.name.startswith(""):
            new_name = "" + interaction.channel.name[1:]
            await interaction.channel.edit(name=new_name)
            await interaction.response.send_message("> **You have updated the status of this channel.**", ephemeral=True)

        else:
            new_name = ""+interaction.channel.name
            await interaction.channel.edit(name=new_name)
            await interaction.response.send_message("> **You have updated the status of this channel.**", ephemeral=True)
    
    @app_commands.command(name="yellow", description="Mark this channel with a yellow emoji: ")

    async def yellow(self,interaction:discord.Interaction):
        if interaction.channel.name.startswith(""):
            await interaction.response.send_message("> **This channel is already marked yellow.**", ephemeral=True)
        elif interaction.channel.name.startswith("") or interaction.channel.name.startswith(""):
            new_name = "" + interaction.channel.name[1:]
            await interaction.channel.edit(name=new_name)
            await interaction.response.send_message("> **You have updated the status of this channel.**", ephemeral=True)

        else:
            new_name = ""+interaction.channel.name
            await interaction.channel.edit(name=new_name)
            await interaction.response.send_message("> **You have updated the status of this channel.**", ephemeral=True)

async def setup(bot):
    bot.tree.add_command(ColorGroup(name="set", description="Placeholder"))
```

To summarize colors.py: It just renames the channel the slash command is used in. There's a lot more color options, 4 more which I didn't include

I was told that adding `@app_commands.checks.cooldown(2,600.0,key=lambda i:(i.channel.id))`  would apply that check to a whole group. However, I think the issue more lies in the fact that I have separate file to organize this slash command group. Because in my testing with just a simple response command, I can't get check cooldowns to work in any way. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong:

1. My implementation of cooldowns is wrong so my error handler can't catch.
   or
2. By having a separate file the error handler and checks won't work at all.

I have tried adding app_commands.checks.cooldown singularly to the slash command group. However if you, for example, use color A then color B then color C the checks cooldown does not apply correctly. Since cooldowns are limited to that singular slash command. Another option would be to bring colors.py into the original file rather than have it be separated and loaded. However I don't like this implementation due to it getting very messy in the original file (and I still don't know how to apply a cooldown to a whole slash command group this way anyways).